# Understanding how Chrome names its javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to dig into JavaScript's inner mechanisms and ran accross an interesting case that I'll simplify:

Can you help me understand the following scenario:

```
Q = {};

Q.Human = function(){
    this.walk = function(){ ... }
};
console.debug(new Q.Human()); // » Q.Human {walk: function}

Q.go = function(fn){
    return fn;
}
Q.SuperHuman = Q.go(function(){
    this.fly = function(){ ... }
});
console.debug(new Q.SuperHuman()); // » Object {fly: function}
```

Both return the correct objects with the expected methods.

Yet one is displayed as a Q.Human, the other as an Object.

Can someone explain? How can I get it to display Q.SuperHuman?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `Q.SuperHuman = Q.go(function SuperHuman(){...`

Comment: That will skip the namespace, won't it? Also is it possible to bypass the repetition somehow?

Comment: I don't know of any way to bypass the repetition without ugly hacks using `eval`. There'll be no difference with respect to the namespace *(I assume by that you mean the `Q` object)*. There will be a variable `SuperHuman` created, but it will only be inside that function, so it won't pollute the outer variable scope *(except in older IE, where the name escapes)*.